# How to load only user profile in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am new to codeigniter. I have a system where I have three users: superadmin, admin and just the user. The superadmin can create admin and the admin can create users and view them but cannot see other admins created by superadmin. Now I want users to only view only their own profile and not all the users in database. How can I accomplish this?

The Controller:

```
 public function index ()
{
    // Fetch all users
    $this->data['users'] = $this->client_m->get();


    // Load view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'client/user/index';
    $this->load->view('client/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

//get function returns all the users in database but i want only the current user

The Model:

```
 public function login ()
{
    $user = $this->get_by(array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),

    ), TRUE);

    if (count($user)) {
        // Log in user
        $data = array(

            'email' => $user->email,


            'id' => $user->id,

            'loggedin' => TRUE,
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <section>
        <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr class="success">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if(count($users)): foreach($users as $user): ?>   
        <tr class="info">
        <td><?php echo anchor('client/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->name); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor('client/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->email); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor('client/user/edit/' . $user->id, $user->balance); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo btn_edit('client/user/edit/' . $user->id); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo btn_delete('client/user/delete/' . $user->id); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </section>
        </div>
```

I am fetching all users currently but i just want to show the user only his profile and not other users details.

Comment: so pass user id  in where clause and fetch only one record for login user

Comment: @user1048123 Pass user id ? where? should i pass it in my controller ? and how to fetch it in my view file?

Comment: While fecthing the data from database, add where clause with that user id whose details you want to view.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$this->client_m->get();
```

make and use something like this

```
$this->client_m->get_users_profile();
```

Since you are storing the logged in user in a session, use that and in get_users_profile() do something like this (using your own column and table names of course):

```
$this->db->select('uid, name, balance, etc');
$query = $this->db->get_where('users_profiles', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id')));
return $query->result();
```

That alone will do what you want to do, but you should have some logic in your controller to make decisions based on permission level. Since you are using sessions, I would suggest one more session variable, "role", where you can store the users permission level. Then in your controllers you can make deciisons based on role. For example, if you have an admin controller that shows an admin page, you can check the role of the logged in user and if they are not an admin, you can redirect them. This may also help you in profiles since you may want combinations of things to work like if you're an admin, you can see all profiles but if you are a regular user you can only see yours. In other words, you need the extra level of information everywhere to make better decisions, so you may as well store role and use it in combination with other data to make decisions.

Comment: Thanks! but can i ask a little more help? is there any tutorial on how to assign these  permissions and add logic in database regarding the currently logged in user? I have seen many Auth Library but i actully dont know how to use them!

Comment: Try using flexi auth. They have these features. It might look confusing while trying for the first time. But it really helps once you get into it. Check their documentation http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/user_guide/installation or you could try their Codeigniter-3-RC2-with-Flexiauth from https://github.com/leap-it/Flexi-Auth-and-Codeigniter-3RC2. It really saves time, only need to bring in your custom design...

Comment: Unfortunately your question is too broad. There are 1000s of answers. Its up to you to decide. When I say "save permission level in a session variable" I mean add to you session something like: 'role' => 0 (or whatever works for you). Even using flexi auth (or anything else) you will have to understand how to modify code and learn how the system works. If you're at a level you need to learn how to add information to the database, you should probably go through basic codeigniter tutorials first.

Comment: Thanks , i will go through its documentation

Comment: @greco.roamin  so for table session i must add a field like role=>0 for admin, 1 for something else. is it so? because i just copy pasted the code and got error like: Table 'content.users_profiles' doesn't exist

SELECT `uid`, `name`, `balance`, `etc` FROM (`users_profiles`) WHERE `id` = '2'

Comment: @jones Hi, Can you please show me the code to fetch the username email and balance from database for the currently loggedin user. i have a function setup : public function loggedin ()
 {
  return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
 }    so just tell me how to put the condition while fetching the single record for loggedin user.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using flexi auth, you can create privileges from admin panel for User Groups. When an user logins, he will be logged in with session values such as name, email, group, and all his privileges. (Which he got from the Group). You could then use the flexi auth privilege checking condition

```
if (! $this->flexi_auth->is_privileged('View Users'))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p class="error_msg">You do not have privileges to view user accounts.</p>');
        redirect('auth_admin');
    }
else{
     //User has the View Users privilege. Do this.. 
    }
```

Download the demo files and check... It will be much easier.